# Get Variable from SageMaker Script Processor

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow2.0, amazon-sagemaker

I am using SageMaker for distributed TensorFlow model training and serving.  I am trying to get the shape of the pre-processed datasets from the ScriptProcessor so I can provide it to the TensorFlow Environment.

```
script_processor = ScriptProcessor(command=['python3'],
                image_uri=preprocess_img_uri,
                role=role,
                instance_count=1,
                sagemaker_session=sm_session,
                instance_type=preprocess_instance_type)

script_processor.run(code=preprocess_script_uri,
                inputs=[ProcessingInput(
                        source=source_dir + username + '/' + dataset_name,
                        destination='/opt/ml/processing/input')],
                outputs=[
                        ProcessingOutput(output_name="train_data", source="/opt/ml/processing/train"),
                        ProcessingOutput(output_name="test_data", source="/opt/ml/processing/test")
                ],

                arguments = ['--filepath', dataset_name, '--labels', 'labels', '--test_size', '0.2', '--shuffle', 'False', '--lookback', '5',])

preprocessing_job_description = script_processor.jobs[-1].describe()

output_config = preprocessing_job_description["ProcessingOutputConfig"]
for output in output_config["Outputs"]:
    if output["OutputName"] == "train_data":
        preprocessed_training_data = output["S3Output"]["S3Uri"]
    if output["OutputName"] == "test_data":
        preprocessed_test_data = output["S3Output"]["S3Uri"]
```

I would like to get the following data:

```
pre_processed_train_data_shape = script_processor.train_data_shape?
```

I am just not sure how to get the value out of the docker container.  I have reviewed the documentation here:https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/processing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options:

1. Write some data to a text file at `/opt/ml/output/message`, then call [DescribeProcessingJob](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sagemaker/describe-processing-job.html) (using Boto3 or the AWS CLI or API) and retrieve the `ExitMessage` value

   ```
   aws sagemaker describe-processing-job \
     --processing-job-name foo \
     --output text \
     --query ExitMessage
   ```
2. Add a new output to your processing job and send data there
3. If your `train_data` is in CSV, JSON, or Parquet then use an [S3 Select query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/select-object-content.html) on `train_data` for it's # of rows/columns

   ```
   aws s3api select-object-content \
     --bucket foo \
     --key 'path/to/train_data.csv' \
     --expression "SELECT count(*) FROM s3object" \
     --expression-type 'SQL' \
     --input-serialization '{"CSV": {}}' \
     --output-serialization '{"CSV": {}}' /dev/stdout
   ```

Set `expression` to `select * from s3object limit 1` to get the columns

Comment: Neil thanks for your response.  It seems that all of those options require writing the data to a source somewhere and then finding and loading that data again.  I guess I was hoping for an easier server-side code solution.  I will mark your solution as the answer.